# Way of tracking prolog recursion depth?

Tags: recursion, prolog

in prolog I have my database set up like this

```
male("John").
male("Bob").
male("Billy").
male("Gary").

Parent("Bob","John").
Parent("Billy","Bob").
Parent("Gary", "Billy").


ancestor(Ancestor, Descendant) :-
    parent(Ancestor, Descendant).
ancestor(Ancestor, Descendant) :-
    parent(Ancestor, CommonAncestor),
    ancestor(CommonAncestor, Descendant).
```

Would it be possible to track how far into recursion this ancestor function went? for example if we ran

```
?- ancestor("Billy", "John", X).
```

Would it be possible to have X return 2, or in the case of

```
?- ancestor("Bob", "John", X).
```

have X return 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo could write:

```
ancestor(Ancestor, Descendant,1) :-
    parent(Ancestor, Descendant).
ancestor(Ancestor, Descendant,X) :-
    parent(Ancestor, CommonAncestor),
    ancestor(CommonAncestor, Descendant,X1),
    X is X1+1.
```

Some examples:

```
?- ancestor("Billy", "John", X).
X = 2 ;
false.

?- ancestor("Bob", "John", X).
X = 1 ;
false.
```